# Can I create a signed Amazon S3 GET request without Expires

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to Amazon S3 and using unique identifiers to ensure there is no conflicts. After uploading I want to cache a link in the database to the file with the "response-content-type" and "response-content-disposition" parameters.

Unfortunately this necessitates signing the URL, and it seems that all signed URLs require an expires parameter.

I don't want this link to expire. I don't see why it should need to expire.

Is the only way to deal with this is to create the link on the fly for every request to the resource?  I don't like the idea of creating links with some arbitrary far off future date.

---

Edit:

I have added the Content-Type and Content-Disposition parameters to the POST operation which are then returned/used with the GET operation. I did not realize this when I asked this question.  The question is still a valid question so I'll leave it up for a bit more to see if there are any other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL signing is for giving temporary access to someone who you do not want to share credentials with. There is no way to sign an S3 URL without an expiration. You may want to look at setting your objects to public read which will allow you to download them without having to sign them and they do not expire.

More information on why it needs to expire and exactly what they're doing when they sign the url. http://www.layer7tech.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-hmac-api-security

Comment: I understand that, my question involves files which are currently set to public read, however I want the URL to also have the response header overrides in it.

Comment: Response header overrides cannot be used in conjunction with anonymous GET requests. See the first note under the Requests header here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html